# How to view performance history if we invested in the past?

Tags: index-fund, stock-markets, market-indexes

I want to look at a scenario to see how the Getty Trust with [$1.2 billion in 1982](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/getty-museum-endowed) would have performed had it stayed with just an index fund such as S&P 500. Bonus, if there is a way to take out 5% each year from the trust fund.

I tried using Yahoo! daily export to CSV. I get that $1.2 billion would be a specific number of shares per day. I also understand the value today would be about $20 billion. I just don't know how to take out 5% each year as an operating budget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've downloaded an S&P 500 fund data you point to over the time period from February 1982 until the present, and [made an attempt to set up a spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0trsKltQTHAQnFUQjl3SHdETkU/view?usp=sharing) that removes the fraction in cell `K1` from the value of number of shares in the fund at or close to the March 1st anniversary dates.

Below is a plot that shows three scenarios:

- Not removing anything from the fund (blue).
- Removing 5% from the fund every anniversary date (red).
- Removing 10% from the fund every anniversary date (green).

Note that this takes zero account of dividends paid by the fund, which should also probably be taken into account.

[image]

Comment: I guess since the current value of the Trust is $6.7 billion, it is beating the index by a large margin. Thanks for the analysis. I am still not sure how you removed the 5% and 10% by calculation, but I appreciate the analysis.

Comment: If you check in the cells showing the number of "shares" in the S&P 500, it just carries on except for every anniversary date. On that date, I just multiply the previous number of shares by `1-K1` and so the number is reduced (provided `K1` is positive!).

Comment: Also, don't forget those dividends.  That probably won't make up the entire difference between what is calculated and $6.7 billion, but it will probably make up a bit.

Comment: That's not in the Yahoo! CSV I though. Or perhaps I missed that as a feature.

Comment: No, I added a few columns and converted to a Microsoft Excel file... and uploaded it to Google Drive. The data is columns `A` through `G` is straight out of Yahoo.